# CSP blocks when page is requested by IP

Tags: html, content-security-policy

My CSP rules are quite simple / standard:

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' https://www.googleapis.com https://api.dropboxapi.com https://content.dropboxapi.com;img-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline' data:;base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';object-src 'none';upgrade-insecure-requests
```

And they work, but only when the page is called via a `name:port`, and *not* an IP adress.

Both `tld:PORT` and `localhost:PORT` work, but not `IP:PORT` despite the `'self'` keyword in `default-src`.

Is there a way to get the rules to work when the page is called by IP, or is it inherently impossible?

Comment: Great question, @yPhil. According to the specification of the host matching, it will allow only `127.0.0.1` https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-hosts when it comes to the rules themselves. I assume that the same logic applies to the `self` keyword in directives. That said, I don't see any ways of having it working using `IP:PORT` right now.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered some strange behavior for my local environment and I think it's related to your question. My local server is on http but chrome tries to load everything through https when I set the CSP.

Call to index :
[image]

And from here every request is loaded through https:

[image]

I don't know what "CSP magic" causes this behavior but switching to NAME:PORT instead of the ip address fix the issue.

Comment: Hey, answering my own question here: I'm using expressJS with Helmet to manage my CSP, and by default it sets the upgrade-insecure-requests header automatically. I had to override it : 

``` lang-js    
 this.app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
        directives: {
          ...,
          upgradeInsecureRequests : null
        }
      }));
```